# Run a gulp plugin that requires the current file path and name

Tags: gulp, css-purge

I am using purgeCSS to removed unused CSS. My challenge is that I need to do this dynamically. Depending on the current .css file that is being processed, I need to get its path and file name so I can dynamically insert the content HTML path for Purge to run.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
    appRoot = require("app-root-path"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    purgecss = require("gulp-purgecss"),
    tap = require("gulp-tap"),
    path = require("path"),
    utilities = require(appRoot + "/Tools/Utilities-Functions/utilities-functions.js");

gulp.task("sass", () => {
    let htmlContentPath = "";

    return (
        gulp
            .src("./Pages/**/*.scss")
            // Compile .scss into .css
            .pipe(sass())
            // Get path for HTML file (dynamic)
            .pipe(
                tap(function (file, t) {
                    let fileName = path.basename(file.path);
                    // This is a simple function that returns the file name without extension (homepage.css >> homepage)
                    fileName = utilities.getFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                    htmlContentPath = "/fullPath/Pages/" + fileName + "/compiled/html/" + fileName + ".html";
                })
            )
            // Remove unused CSS
            .pipe(
                purgecss({
                    content: [htmlContentPath]
                })
            )
            // Set the destination folder (main css)
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
    );
})
```

For some reason happens that "htmlContentPath" for the Purge is empty. Even though I would expect "tap" plugin to always set a value to it. As a result this provokes an error on the purgecss:

[image]

As stated above, this error is due to having "htmlContentPath" empty.

Another attempt I tried was to do the Purge inside the Tap plugin, like this:

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
    appRoot = require("app-root-path"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    purgecss = require("gulp-purgecss"),
    tap = require("gulp-tap"),
    path = require("path"),
    utilities = require(appRoot + "/Tools/Utilities-Functions/utilities-functions.js");

gulp.task("sass", () => {
    return (
        gulp
            .src("./Pages/**/*.scss")
            // Compile .scss into .css
            .pipe(sass())
            // Get path for HTML file (dynamic)
            .pipe(
                tap(function (file, t) {
                    let fileName = path.basename(file.path);
                    // This is a simple function that returns the file name without extension (homepage.css >> homepage)
                    fileName = utilities.getFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                    let htmlContentPath = "/fullPath/Pages/" + fileName + "/compiled/html/" + fileName + ".html";

                    // Remove unused CSS
                    purgecss({
                        content: [htmlContentPath]
                    })
                })
            )
            // Set the destination folder (main css)
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
    );
})
```

This time it doesn't give an error, but the Purge is totally ignored...

Any solution on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting dozens of approaches here is the one that worked for me and thought would be worth sharing with others that might be going through a similar challenge:

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
    appRoot = require("app-root-path"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    path = require("path"),
    utilities = require(appRoot + "/Tools/Utilities-Functions/utilities-functions.js"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    through = require("through2"),
    uncss = require("uncss");

gulp.task("sass", () => {
    return (
        gulp
            .src("./Pages/**/*.scss")
            // Compile .scss into .css
            .pipe(sass())
            // Remove unused CSS
            .pipe(
                through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
                    try {
                        const cssFileContent = file.contents.toString(); // Get the css file contents
                        let transformedFile = file.clone(), // Clone new  file for manipulation
                            fileName = path.basename(file.path),
                            htmlFilePath;

                        // This is a simple function that returns the file name without extension (homepage.css >> homepage)
                        fileName = utilities.getFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                        // File path for the .html file
                        htmlFilePath = "/fullPath/Pages/" + fileName + "/compiled/html/" + fileName + ".html";

                        // Check if there is any css to be checked and if .html file exists
                        if (cssFileContent.length && fs.existsSync(htmlFilePath)) {
                            // Call uncss to remove unused css
                            uncss([htmlFilePath], { raw: cssFileContent }, function(error, output) {
                                if (error) {
                                    callback(null, transformedFile);
                                }

                                // Set new contents with the "used" css only (uncss' output)
                                transformedFile.contents = Buffer.from(output);

                                callback(null, transformedFile);
                            });
                        } else {
                            callback(null, transformedFile);
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log("Gulp error - uncss: " + e.message);
                        callback(null, transformedFile);
                    }
                })
            )
            // Set the destination folder (main css)
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
    );
});
```

Basically I built a custom gulp stream using **[through](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2)**. This allows you to read information about the current file processed, do whatever logic you want, and then invoke **callback** with the new transformed file.

In more details what I have done:

1. Read file information (file name and its location)
2. Get the location for the HTML I want to check my CSS against
3. Run [uncss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncss) (instead of purgecss I was using initially) because on this tool I can send raw CSS which is handy in my case
4. From the output of uncss, I affect the contents of the CSS file with this output
5. Invoke callback with this new transformed file